# Insert date from a DropDownBox into an SQL column

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2014

so heres my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source= *** ;Integrated Security=True;";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string queryString = "INSERT INTO [Iliako_Sistima] (name,apostasi_apo_earth,arithmos_planiton,imerominia_entopismou) VALUES ('"+TextBoxName.Text+"','"+TextBoxEarthDistance.Text+"','"+TextBoxPlanets.Text+"','"+DropDownMonth.Text+"'/'"+DropDownDay.Text+"'/'"+DropDownYear.Text+"');";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Response.Redirect("Error.aspx", true);
        }
        conn.Close();
        //Response.Redirect("NewSolar.aspx", false);
    }
```

i want to insert in the column "imerominia_entopismou" the date selected in the 3 DropDownBoxes (DropDownDay,DropDownMonth,DropDownYear)

the problem is that this code ('"+DropDownMonth.Text+"'/'"+DropDownDay.Text+"'/'"+DropDownYear.Text+"') wont do that because he gets an sql error

how can i succeed what i want?

Comment: Firstly, don't use concatenated values for the insert because you might  run into SQL Injection issues. Use parameterized queries. Then try without the single quotes ' ' between the "/".

Comment: isnt any way to do that this way?

Comment: What's the sql error you get? Also check my edited comment.

Comment: YES! that was it ...you were right there was no need of '' between the dashes... thanks a lot! ..Ευχαριστω Πολυ φιλε μου! :)

Comment: Nothing!!Can i am putting it as answer, ok! Τίποτα χαρά μου!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the single quotes ' ' between the "/".